# Java food menu - unable to store user input and review after

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Java and have started a basic project creating a food menu. I've managed to get the first part of the user selecting pizza toppings and this storing so the user can view order at the main menu, however I'm getting issues when trying to store options for beverages. I have separate classes set up for pizza, beverages and viewOrder which I can copy into the chat if needed. Appreciate any feedback on what to do and how I've set the code up already as I'm keen to learn!

After the user selects a drink it takes them back to the main menu. When selecting view order it returns the error message to say that their order is empty. I think it might be related to the if statement within view order.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput; // Declare the variable outside the loop

        String selectedPizza = null;
        ArrayList<String> selectedToppings = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> selectedDrinks = new ArrayList<>(); // Declare the ArrayList for drinks

        while (true) {
            Order.orderMenu(); // Display the menu
            userInput = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine(); // Consume the newline character

            if (userInput == 1) {
                FoodMenu.displayMenu();

                int userInput1 = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.nextLine();

                if (userInput1 == 1) {
                    selectedPizza = "Pizza"; // Store the selected food option

                    // Collect user's topping selections
                    int toppingsSelected = 0;
                    while (toppingsSelected < 4) { // asks the user to select 4 toppings
                        System.out.print("Select a topping: ");
                        String topping = scanner.nextLine(); // user input
                        selectedToppings.add(topping); // adds toppings selected
                        toppingsSelected++;
                    }
                } else if (userInput1 == 2) {
                    // User gets given drinks options to order here
                    Beverages.drinkOptions();

                    String selectedDrink = Beverages.getDrinkChoice(scanner);
                    if (selectedDrink != null) {
                            selectedDrinks.add(selectedDrink);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Please enter a valid drink number.");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid selection.");
                }
            } else if (userInput == 2) {
                // View order logic
                if (selectedPizza != null) {
                    OrderView.viewOrder(selectedPizza, selectedToppings, selectedDrinks);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Your order is empty, please add an item from the menu first.");
                }
            } else if (userInput == 3) {
                System.out.println("Thank you, your order is on the way");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid selection.");
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a general comment: don't add comments that say what the code does. It's already obvious from the code. Only add comments to say _why_ you're doing what you're doing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with how you're checking for an empty order before displaying it. You're correctly checking if selectedPizza is null, but you also need to check if selectedToppings or selectedDrinks are empty or not. Here's the modified view order logic to address this:

```
} else if (userInput == 2) {
    // View order logic
    if (selectedPizza != null || !selectedToppings.isEmpty() || !selectedDrinks.isEmpty()) {
        OrderView.viewOrder(selectedPizza, selectedToppings, selectedDrinks);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your order is empty, please add an item from the menu first.");
    }
}
```

And, next issue might be in your Beverages class. You mentioned that you have a getDrinkChoice method. Make sure this method correctly handles the user input and returns the selected drink. Here's an example of how the method might look:

```
public class Beverages {
    public static String getDrinkChoice(Scanner scanner) {
        int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); // Consume the newline character

        switch (userInput) {
            case 1:
                return "Coke";
            case 2:
                return "Sprite";
            case 3:
                return "Water";
            default:
                return null; // Return null for invalid choices
        }
    }
}
```

Good Luck.